# Can't install pythonbrew 2.6

Tags: python, linux, pythonbrew

I'm trying to install python 2.6 with pythonbrew but i received some error while running the command

```
pythonbrew install --configure="--enable-unicode=ucs4" 2.6
```

I'm running under Archlinux and used python2.7 for a long time on that machine. But I need to have both 2.6 and 2.7 on my machine so a pythonbrew install seemed ok.

Here is the error :

```
Parser/pgen ./Grammar/Grammar ./Include/graminit.h ./Python/graminit.c
Parser/pgen ./Grammar/Grammar ./Include/graminit.h ./Python/graminit.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude I./Include  -fPIC -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/symtable.o Python/symtable.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include  -fPIC -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/compile.o Python/compile.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include  -fPIC -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/graminit.o Python/graminit.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include  -fPIC -DPy_BUILD_CORE -DSVNVERSION=\"`LC_ALL=C svnversion .`\" -o Modules/getbuildinfo.o ./Modules/getbuildinfo.c
gcc: error: directory": No such file or directory
make: *** [Modules/getbuildinfo.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution to this [here](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/14).  Basically the behaviour of `svnversion` changed at some point and the work around is to put a script named `svnversion` in your path while building python 2.6.2

```
#!/bin/sh
echo exported
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know what causes this error, it is possible to work around this by using Python 2.6.8 instead:

```
pythonbrew install --configure="--enable-unicode=ucs4" 2.6.8
```